# PHP, SQL: Only store two line breaks from user input

Tags: php, mysql

The user can make input into this:

```
<textarea name="sometext"></textarea>
```

I want to only store max two line breaks. So for example:

Correct 1 (simple line break):

```
This should be stored
This should be stored
```

Correct 2:

```
This should be stored too

This should be stored too
```

Wrong:

```
This should NOT be stored


This should NOT be stored
```

If it is wrong it should be automatically converted to example 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just count the line breaks, you can use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr_count):

```
if (substr_count($input, "\n") > 2) {
    echo 'Invalid input';
}
```

Comment: that would return true if there were multiple lines.

Comment: Actually, the OP says that they want to store a *max two line breaks* and they don't have to be empty.

Comment: True, but I think what OP is really looking for is two line breaks after a sentence based on the examples. Wording a question correctly is important I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to avoid more then one blank line, in which case the following should be sufficient.

```
 $l1 = "This should be stored
 This should be stored";

 $l2 = "This should be stored too

 This should be stored too";

 $l3 = "This should NOT be stored


 This should NOT be stored";

 $expected_l3 = "This should NOT be stored

 This should NOT be stored";


 $examples = array($l1, $l2, $l3);
 $results = array();

 foreach ($examples as $example) {
   $lines = explode("\n", $example);
   $result = array();
   $blankLine = False;
   foreach ($lines as $ii => $line) {
     $line = trim($line);

     if ($blankLine and !$line) {
       continue;
     }
     $blankLine = False;

     $result[] = $line;

     if (!$line) {
       $blankLine = True;
     } 
   }

   $results[] = implode("\n", $result);
 }

 assert($results[0] == $l1);
 assert($results[1] == $l2);
 assert($results[2] == $expected_l3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to store a max of 2 new lines per string. So we need to divide this string by the number of `\n` occurrences.

```
$data = "This should be stored too\nThis should be stored too";

$lines = preg_split("/\n/", $data);

var_dump($lines);


$data2 = "This should NOT be stored\n\n\nThis should NOT be stored";


$lines = preg_split("/\n/", $data2);

var_dump($lines);

$newlines = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if($lines[$i] == '') {
        $newlines++;
    }
}

if($newlines > 2) {
    // do the conersion here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Anonymous almost has it. It seems like it should be something like the below, if I understand what you are looking for.

```
if(substr_count($input,"\n\n\n")>0){
     $input=str_replace("\n\n\n","\n\n",$input); 
}
```

This will look for two line breaks and if they're found it will remove them.

Comment: you could also use strpos instead of substr_count... actually, that's probably ideal.